# MySQL Or SQL: References from multiply table

Tags: mysql

I need some help with a database I am creating. I have a database call School which have multiply table such as **Admin, Teacher, Student, and Login**. The Login table have a FOREIGN KEY called EMPID. I want the EMPID to references EMP from the Admin, Teacher, and Student table. Below are the tables

```
CREATE TABLE Admin(
  EMP INT NOT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  Email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  Phone VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (EMP)
)ENGINE = innoDB;

CREATE TABLE Teacher (
  EMP INT NOT NULL,
  Name VARCHAR (60) NOT NULL,
  Email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  Phone VARCHAR (12) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (EMP)

)ENGINE = innoDB;

Create Table Student(
  EMP INT NOT NULL,
  TEMP INT NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
  Email VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
  Phone VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,

  PRIMARY KEY (EMP),

  CONSTRAINT TEMP_fk FOREIGN KEY (TEMP) REFERENCES Teacher (EMP)

)ENGINE = innoDB;

CREATE TABLE Login(
  LID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  EMPID INT NOT NULL,
  Username VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
  Password VARCHAR (12) NOT NULL,
  UserType VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (LID),

  CONSTRAINT EMPID_fk FOREIGN KEY (EMPID) REFERENCES Teacher (EMP),
  CONSTRAINT EMPID_fk FOREIGN KEY (EMPID) REFERENCES Student (EMP)
)ENGINE = innoDB;
```

When I run it, I keep getting these error message.

> [HY000][1215] Cannot add foreign key constraint
>
> [42S02][1146] Table 'vwcc.login' doesn't exist

Comment: Why are you creating two foreign keys on the Login table with the same name but different references?  `EMPID_fk`

Comment: Tag only the dbms you are using. It is pointless and aggravating to others to tag "extras". You are not using sql server.

Comment: What you are trying to do makes no sense. Even if it were permitted; when you had the value 1 in Login.EMPID, where would it "point", the Teacher record with EMP = 1, or the Student record with EMP = 1. T.Palludan's answer below has the right idea; you need a `users` table for all the other tables you've shown to reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it would be a better idea to make a "user" table that admin, teacher, and student inherits properties from.

So the user would have a username, password, firstname, lastname, and so forth, which the login table could reference.

While the admin, teacher, and student tables could have information relevant for just this type of user.